# Calling a helper function requiring dispatch from thunk

Tags: redux

I'm using Redux Toolkit, though I don't think that makes a difference.

I've set up a snackbar that reads from `store.data.message`, and I write the message by setting a value and then clearing the message after a timeout. This happens in a helper function, `showMessage`.

I call `showMessage` from my thunks:

```js
export const showMessage = (dispatch: any, message: string) => {
  dispatch(setMessage(message))
  setTimeout(() => dispatch(clearMessage()), 3000)
}

export const fetchDataState = (): AppThunk => async dispatch => {
  const state = await getSystemState()
  showMessage(dispatch, 'Fetched system state.')
  dispatch(getStateSucceeded(state))
}
```

I simply want to know if there is a way to write these without having to pass `dispatch` in every time I call `showMessage`.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I imagine I can't write it like a thunk because `redux-thunk` is middleware that calls the thunks in its own way, and I'm not calling them that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write it as a thunk like this:

```js
export const showMessage = (message: string) => (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  dispatch(setMessage(message))
  setTimeout(() => dispatch(clearMessage()), 3000)
}

// call it: 
dispatch(showMessage("Hi!"))
```